# I try to use Lifting State Up in Flutter, but I get "Closure call with mismatched arguments"

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state, parent-child

I pass Data from parent to child, and one of these parameters is a Fn. What I need is to return data from child to parent again, but I get an error as below:

> [ Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_ReservationBranchesSlotsScreenState._changeData' Receiver: Closure:
> ({String areaId, int coastPerPerson, int selectedBranchChecked, String
> formatted, bool showCreateReservationButton, bool isExpanded, int
> expandedIndex}) => void from Function '_changeData@176179245':. Tried
> calling: _ReservationBranchesSlotsScreenState._changeData(areaId:
> "d98a4e0e-d408-40c8-b387-9a405683a389", coastPerPerson: 0,
> expandedIndex: -1, formatted: null, isExpanded: false,
> selectedBrnachChecked: 0, showCreateReservationButton: false) Found:
> _ReservationBranchesSlotsScreenState._changeData({String areaId, int coastPerPerson, int selectedBranchChecked, String formatted, bool
> showCreateReservationButton, bool isExpanded, int expandedIndex}) =>
> void ]

I create a Function in the parent Widget that do some actions, and pass this Fn to the child widget as below.

This is the parent widget Fn:

```
void _changeData({
  String areaId,  
  int coastPerPerson,
  int selectedBranchChecked,
  String formatted,
  bool showCreateReservationButton,
  bool isExpanded,
  int expandedIndex
  }){
    setState(() {
          _areaId = areaId;
          _coastPerPerson = coastPerPerson;
          _selectedBranchChecked = selectedBranchChecked;
          _formatted = formatted; 
          _showCreateReservationButton = showCreateReservationButton;
          _isExpanded = isExpanded;
          _expandedIndex = expandedIndex;
        });
  }
```

also below when I pass this Fn to the child widget:

```
SelectBranchWidget(
    branches: _branches,
    coastPerPerson: _coastPerPerson,
    areaId: _areaId,
    selectedBranchChecked: _selectedBranchChecked,
    formatted: _formatted,
    isExpanded: _isExpanded,
    showCreateReservationButton: _showCreateReservationButton,
    expandedIndex: _expandedIndex,
    ***changeData: _changeData,***
  ),
```

and here is the child widget which I need to return a Data from it to the parent again:

```
class SelectBranchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<RestaurantBranch> branches;
  int coastPerPerson;
  String areaId;
  int selectedBranchChecked;
  String formatted;
  bool isExpanded;
  bool showCreateReservationButton;
  int expandedIndex;
  Function changeData;
  SelectBranchWidget(
      {this.branches,
      this.coastPerPerson,
      this.areaId,
      this.selectedBranchChecked,
      this.formatted,
      this.isExpanded,
      this.showCreateReservationButton,
      this.expandedIndex,
      this.changeData,
      });
  @override
  _SelectBranchWidgetState createState() => _SelectBranchWidgetState();
}

class _SelectBranchWidgetState extends State<SelectBranchWidget> {
  void _changedValues(int i, int branchAreaIndex) {
    widget.coastPerPerson = widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].costPerSeat;
    widget.areaId = widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].guid;
    print('areaId IS ${widget.areaId}');
      widget.selectedBranchChecked = i;
      widget.formatted = null;
      widget.isExpanded = false;
      widget.showCreateReservationButton = false;
      widget.expandedIndex = -1;
    widget.changeData(
      areaId: widget.areaId, 
      coastPerPerson: widget.coastPerPerson, 
      selectedBrnachChecked:widget.selectedBranchChecked,
      formatted: widget.formatted,
       showCreateReservationButton:widget.showCreateReservationButton,
      isExpanded:widget.isExpanded,
      expandedIndex: widget.expandedIndex
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Select Branch',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Number of branches = ${widget.branches.length}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
                BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 230, maxWidth: double.infinity),
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.branches.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1) {
                      _changedValues(i, 0);
                      return;
                    }
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                            title: Text(
                              'Select Area',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            content: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),

                              // height: (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1)
                              //     ?70
                              //     : (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 2)
                              //     ? 100
                              //     :150,
                              width: 100.0,
                              child: ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 120),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount:
                                      widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                       _changedValues(i, index);
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 16, left: 36.0, right: 36),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              widget.branches[i]
                                                  .branchAreas[index].name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            Divider(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                              thickness: 1,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.branches[i].branchDistrict.name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          (widget.selectedBranchChecked == i)
                              ? Container(
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 40,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    getAssetsName(AssetsImage.checkIcon),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 40,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  child: SizedBox(),
                                ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches to achieve this.

User first one if you want to return from a route (from next screen to previous one)

Use second Approach if you want to make changes to Parent Widget from its child widget on same screen.

#### 1st Approach (Returning an object from route)

Create a Model of data you are passing.

```
class MyModel {
  int coastPerPerson;
  String areaId;
  int selectedBranchChecked;
  String formatted;
  bool isExpanded;
  bool showCreateReservationButton;
  int expandedIndex;
  Function changeData;

  MyModel({
    this.areaId,
    this.coastPerPerson,
    this.selectedBranchChecked,
    this.formatted ,
    this.isExpanded,
    this.showCreateReservationButton,
    this.expandedIndex,
  });

}
```

I'm assuming that You Parent Looks like this. And you're navigating from Parent Page to
SelectBranchWidget page

```
class YourParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  YourParentWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YourParentWidgetState createState() => _YourParentWidgetState();
}

class _YourParentWidgetState extends State<YourParentWidget> {


  navigateAndChangeData(){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return SelectBranchWidget();
    })).then((value) {
      ///Use this to get value from next screen to PArent Screen
      if(value != null) {
        var model = value as MyModel;
        //Now you have access to all returning values
        //model.areaId
        //model.coastPerPerson
        //model.selectedBranchChecked
        //...
        ///Make changes accordingly
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ///Your UI Conponents....
    );
  }
}
```

Now In SelectBranchWidget Widget, What you need to do in `_changedValues` function is to return model values. i.e.

```
class SelectBranchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<RestaurantBranch> branches;
  int coastPerPerson;
  String areaId;
  int selectedBranchChecked;
  String formatted;
  bool isExpanded;
  bool showCreateReservationButton;
  int expandedIndex;
  Function changeData;
  SelectBranchWidget(
      {this.branches,
        this.coastPerPerson,
        this.areaId,
        this.selectedBranchChecked,
        this.formatted,
        this.isExpanded,
        this.showCreateReservationButton,
        this.expandedIndex,
        this.changeData,
      });
  @override
  _SelectBranchWidgetState createState() => _SelectBranchWidgetState();
}

class _SelectBranchWidgetState extends State<SelectBranchWidget> {
  void _changedValues(int i, int branchAreaIndex) {
    MyModel model = MyModel(
        areaId: widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].guid,
        coastPerPerson: widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].costPerSeat,
        selectedBranchChecked: 1,
        formatted: null,
        isExpanded: false,
        showCreateReservationButton: false,
        expandedIndex: -1
    );

    Navigator.of(context).pop(model);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Select Branch',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Number of branches = ${widget.branches.length}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
            BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 230, maxWidth: double.infinity),
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.branches.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1) {
                      _changedValues(i, 0);
                      return;
                    }
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                            title: Text(
                              'Select Area',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            content: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),

                              // height: (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1)
                              //     ?70
                              //     : (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 2)
                              //     ? 100
                              //     :150,
                              width: 100.0,
                              child: ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 120),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount:
                                  widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        _changedValues(i, index);
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 16, left: 36.0, right: 36),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              widget.branches[i]
                                                  .branchAreas[index].name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            Divider(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                              thickness: 1,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.branches[i].branchDistrict.name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          (widget.selectedBranchChecked == i)
                              ? Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              getAssetsName(AssetsImage.checkIcon),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          )
                              : Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: SizedBox(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 2nd Approach (Making changes to Parent Widget while staying on child Widget)

Make your Parent Widget's State Class and `changeData` function public (i.e. remove underscore before the state class name)
i.e.

```
class YourParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  YourParentWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  YourParentWidgetState createState() => YourParentWidgetState();
}

class YourParentWidgetState extends State<YourParentWidget> {

  String _areaId;
  int _coastPerPerson;
  int _selectedBranchChecked;
  String _formatted;
  bool _showCreateReservationButton;
  bool _isExpanded;
  int _expandedIndex;

  void changeData({
    String areaId,
    int coastPerPerson,
    int selectedBranchChecked,
    String formatted,
    bool showCreateReservationButton,
    bool isExpanded,
    int expandedIndex
  }){
    setState(() {
      _areaId = areaId;
      _coastPerPerson = coastPerPerson;
      _selectedBranchChecked = selectedBranchChecked;
      _formatted = formatted;
      _showCreateReservationButton = showCreateReservationButton;
      _isExpanded = isExpanded;
      _expandedIndex = expandedIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ///Your UI Conponents....
    );
  }
}
```

Then Pass `widget.key` fro YourParentWidget to yor SelectBranchWidget (If you'reusing it inside your UI of YourParentWidget) i.e.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
       children: [
         ///Your UI Conponents....
         SelectBranchWidget(parentKey: widget.key,
           ///... Other PArameters as well
         )
       ],
      )

    );
```

Now in Your `SelectBranchWidget` Widget, do the following

```
class SelectBranchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  GlobalKey<YourParentWidgetState> parentKey;
  List<RestaurantBranch> branches;
  int coastPerPerson;
  String areaId;
  int selectedBranchChecked;
  String formatted;
  bool isExpanded;
  bool showCreateReservationButton;
  int expandedIndex;
  Function changeData;
  SelectBranchWidget(
      {
        this.parentKey,
        this.branches,
        this.coastPerPerson,
        this.areaId,
        this.selectedBranchChecked,
        this.formatted,
        this.isExpanded,
        this.showCreateReservationButton,
        this.expandedIndex,
        this.changeData,
      });
  @override
  _SelectBranchWidgetState createState() => _SelectBranchWidgetState();
}

class _SelectBranchWidgetState extends State<SelectBranchWidget> {
  void _changedValues(int i, int branchAreaIndex) {
    widget.coastPerPerson = widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].costPerSeat;
    widget.areaId = widget.branches[i].branchAreas[branchAreaIndex].guid;
    print('areaId IS ${widget.areaId}');
    widget.selectedBranchChecked = i;
    widget.formatted = null;
    widget.isExpanded = false;
    widget.showCreateReservationButton = false;
    widget.expandedIndex = -1;
    ///Then do this to make changes to your parent widget's state
    widget.parentKey.currentState.changeData(
        areaId: widget.areaId,
        coastPerPerson: widget.coastPerPerson,
        selectedBrnachChecked:widget.selectedBranchChecked,
        formatted: widget.formatted,
        showCreateReservationButton:widget.showCreateReservationButton,
        isExpanded:widget.isExpanded,
        expandedIndex: widget.expandedIndex
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Select Branch',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Number of branches = ${widget.branches.length}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints:
            BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 230, maxWidth: double.infinity),
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.branches.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1) {
                      _changedValues(i, 0);
                      return;
                    }
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                            title: Text(
                              'Select Area',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            content: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),

                              // height: (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 1)
                              //     ?70
                              //     : (_branches[i].branchAreas.length == 2)
                              //     ? 100
                              //     :150,
                              width: 100.0,
                              child: ConstrainedBox(
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 120),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount:
                                  widget.branches[i].branchAreas.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        _changedValues(i, index);
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 16, left: 36.0, right: 36),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              widget.branches[i]
                                                  .branchAreas[index].name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            Divider(
                                              color: Colors.grey,
                                              thickness: 1,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.branches[i].branchDistrict.name,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                          (widget.selectedBranchChecked == i)
                              ? Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              getAssetsName(AssetsImage.checkIcon),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          )
                              : Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: SizedBox(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: You just need to call (wherever you're initiating it from) your `YourParentWidget` like `YourParentWidget(key: GlobalKey<YourParentWidgetState>())`

**Pardon me if any typo occurs**

Comment: I did as your steps, but i got an error [The getter 'currentState' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: currentState], do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I've just edited my answer, You just need to call (wherever you're initiating it from) your `YourParentWidget` like `YourParentWidget(key: GlobalKey<YourParentWidgetState>)`

Comment: I hope this will solve problem you're facing.

Comment: sorry I can not understand what you mean, so could you inform me where can I use this edit exactly

Comment: @AhmadMohy Can you please show the code from where you're navigating/starting the ParentWidget?

Comment: child: Consumer<AuthProvider>(
         ...
              ? (authProv.isAccountVerified)
                  ? FlatButton(
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('Reserve Table'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                          ReservationBranchesSlotsScreen.routeName, 
                          arguments: {
                            'restId': _restaurantDetails.id,
                            'restName' : _restaurantDetails.name
                          });

Comment: @AhmadMohy Not this one, The code from RouteGenerator that is routing `ReservationBranchesSlotsScreen.routeName` route to your Parent Widget.

Comment: ReservationBranchesSlotsScreen.routeName: (context) =>
              ReservationBranchesSlotsScreen(key: GlobalKey<ReservationBranchesSlotsScreenState>),..... if you mean this one,it give me an error [A key that is unique across the entire app.

Global keys uniquely identify elements. Global keys provide access to other objects that are associated with those elements, such as [BuildContext]. For [StatefulWidget]s, global keys also provide access to [State]]

Comment: Can you please add image of error you're getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229777/discussion-between-ahmad-mohy-and-ehtisham-shahid-abbasi).